# Facebook - Invite friends in my website

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I'm developing the facebook invite friends to my website. It's working fine but friends didn't get the notification. I used the following code.

```
<div onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"  /> Invite Facebook Friends </div>
<script>
        FB.init({
            appId : '1580474408872303',
            cookie : true,
            status : true,
            xfbml : true
        });

        function FacebookInviteFriends() {
            FB.ui({
                method : 'apprequests',
                message : 'My Description'
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Once I click the "Invite Facebook Friends" `div`, I will get the facebook login popup and showing the few friends. Once I search the friends name it display and I click the send button but friends didn't get the notification. I attached the popup screen shot.

[image]

and in this popup doesn't show the whole friends list. Can anyone suggest what I did wrong?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what's happening in the Network (POST or GET requests)  when you click the "Send" button ?   (You can do this by using the shortcut CTRL+MAJ+i and selecting the Network section and then click on you "Send" button)

Comment: apprequests are meant to be used for apps, not for external websites... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Comment: for external websites, just use like/share/send plugins.

Comment: I followed the code in this site : http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html#livedemo

Comment: use the facebook docs instead of articles from 2012...

Answer (score 0):

The method `apprequests` is only available for "Games on Facebook", not all web games.

As per their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests):

> Game requests are available for [Games on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook) and for mobile games on iOS and Android.